# Game loop with IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, game-loop

I'm trying to write a very simple game in Haskell.
I have this loop which is the last part, and where I don't really know what to do. Of course it is a loop, so it has to run itself.

```
gameLoop :: User -> IO ()
gameLoop initUser = displayPosition initUser >> gameLoop (applyAction initUser)
  where
    applyAction :: UserAction
    applyAction = maybe id (unsafePerformIO (fmap getUserAction getLine))
```

`getUserAction :: String -> Maybe UserAction` is a function that looks up a string in a map and returns a `UserAction :: User -> User`. Then I do some ugly unpacking (`unsafePerformIO`), which I don't know to circumvent.

I thought this should run, because my type seems to be correct, but it still doesn't.

It says:

```
maybe is applied to too few arguments  AND
couldn't match a1 -> a0 -> a0 with actual type Maybe UserAction, because unsafePerformIO is applied to too few arguments.
```

I don't understand these errors. Can anybody explain how to solve these last problems, or how to get rid of `unsafePerformIO`?

Comment: I suggest you look at `forever` from `Control.Monad`.

Comment: Isn't that executing the same monad over and over? I want to pass along initUser.

Answer (score 3):

**Boilerplate Lecture**

First off, pretend `unsafePerformIO` doesn't exist.  Second, next time please present a more complete code snippet, I'll try to answer but will be making assumptions along the way as a result.

**The Walk-through**

You presented:

```
gameLoop :: User -> IO ()
gameLoop initUser = displayPosition initUser >> gameLoop (applyAction initUser)
```

So it seems you must have some definition for `displayPosition :: User -> IO ()`.  Then below you use `UserAction` which seems to be `type UserAction = User -> User`.

```
applyAction :: UserAction
```

Now you suddenly realize you don't want a `User -> User` type but instead have this `IO` you'd like to do, yielding a `User -> IO User` type:

```
applyAction = maybe id (unsafePerformIO (fmap getUserAction getLine))
```

Instead of making the IO magically, and totally unsafely, disappear you could could define:

```
applyAction :: User -> IO User
applyAction previousUser =
    do ln <- getLine
       case getUserAction ln of
           Nothing -> -- You never said what to do here.
                      -- This is the same logical issue as the missing
                      -- argument to your call to `maybe` above.
                      return previousUser -- XXX do something correct!
           Just act -> return act
```

Going back to the `gameLoop`, the types have changed and we can't use `applyAction initUser :: IO User` where the expected value is `:: User`.  We can, however, use monadic bind or do-notation:

```
gameLoop initUser =
      do displayPosition initUser
         newUser <- applyAction initUser
         gameLoop newUser
```

This is just syntactic sugar for:

```
gameLoop initUser = displayPosition initUser >> applyAction initUser >>= \newUser -> gameLoop newUser
```

Or simply:

```
gameLoop initUser = displayPosition initUser >> applyAction initUser >>= gameLoop
```

**More Rewrites**

That was one solution, but it would be nice to keep the `applyAction` function effect-free (no IO) so you could test it and more easily refactor the program.  Instead of getting a line there how about we get a line in the loop and pass it in:

```
gameLoop initUser =
      do displayPosition initUser
         command <- getLine
         newUser <- applyAction command initUser
         gameLoop newUser

applyAction :: String -> User -> User
applyAction cmd oldState = maybe oldState id (getUserAction ln)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to not use `unsafePerformIO`, use `IO`. Try this:

```
getUserAction <$> getLine :: IO (Maybe UserAction)
```

`<$>` is `fmap`. This is an IO action that gets the user action to perform from the user. Then, use `fromMaybe` to set a deafult value (in this case `id`) to convert your `Maybe UserAction` to a `UserAction`:

```
getAction :: IO UserAction
getAction = fromMaybe id . getUserAction <$> getLine
```

Note that `a . b <$> c` is `(a . b) <$> c`, not `a . (b <$> c)`.

Now you can use this function in one shot in your main loop:

```
gameLoop :: User -> IO ()
gameLoop initUser = displayPosition initUser >> getAction >>= \userAction -> gameLoop (userAction initUser)
```

Or use `do`-notation for the same thing:

```
gameLoop :: User -> IO ()
gameLoop initUser = do
  displayPosition initUser
  userAction <- getAction
  gameLoop (userAction initUser)
```